# Google reCaptcha responds with 405 error and CORS message

Tags: angular, cors, localhost, recaptcha

I had implement Google reCaptchaV3 on my login page
I would like to get the score by sending request to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
My code to sent post request like following

```
var x = this.http.post<RecaptchaResponse>(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${this.secret}&response=${this.token}`, null)
  .pipe(
    map(data => new RecaptchaResponse().deserialize(data)),
        catchError(() => throwError('No Score')),
);
```

However I get the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET&response=TOKEN' from origin 'http://localhost:50000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I did try the following approach:
1) Add 'localhost' on admin console
2) Add 127.0.0.1 on admin console
3) Disable 'Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions' option

However none of above were working.
Any idea on how to test the reCaptcha in localhost?
As it's working on Postman but not on localhost.

**UPDATE**
I had added headers to the request but hit another error

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:50000');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin');
var x = this.http.post<RecaptchaResponse>(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${this.secret}&response=${this.token}`, null, {headers: headers})
      .pipe(
        map(data => new RecaptchaResponse().deserialize(data)),
            catchError(() => throwError('No Score')),
    );
```

Hit error on preflight request

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET&response=TOKEN' from origin 'http://localhost:50000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image]
**UPDATED V2 => SOLUTION**
The question has been closed due to duplicated question.
However the answer from the post did not solve my issue.

I had finally found out using proxy will solve the issue.
The answer from @dasunse is almost get it work.
1) Add a proxy.cong.json with following configuration

```
"/api": {
  "target": "https://www.google.com",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
  },
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true //This is a must if origin from localhost to other domain
}
```

2) Modify the package.json to create proxy

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
  },
```

3) Make request to the url

```
var x = this.http.post<RecaptchaResponse>(`/api/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${this.secret}&response=${this.token}`, null)
  .pipe(
    map(data => new RecaptchaResponse().deserialize(data)),
        catchError(() => throwError('No Score')),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an proxy configuration

Add Headers

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/recaptcha": {
    "target": "https://www.google.com/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
  },
```

In your code

```
LET x = this.http.post<RecaptchaResponse>( `/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${this.secret}&response=${this.token}`, {}, { headers: headers})
  .pipe(
    map(data => new RecaptchaResponse().deserialize(data)),
        catchError(() => throwError('No Score')),
);
```

Comment: Is that means I need to
1) add a json file 'proxy.conf.json' at the root path?
2) modify my package.json to "npm install & ng serve --port 50000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

Comment: @JayChuah yes you have to. Read  https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Comment: There is an error on build time `ERROR in src/app/modules/auth/login/login.component.ts(67,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.`

Comment: use this way  `'google'`

Comment: It hit `POST http://localhost:50000/googlerecaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET&response=TOKEN 404 (Not Found)`. It should sent request to google.com not localhost

Comment: @JayChuah see the updated answer which was edited by chathuran

Comment: Still getting the error `POST http://localhost:50000/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET&response=TOKEN 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: try with stop the app and start again

Comment: Same. It still not working and POST to my localhost

Comment: @JayChuah add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header calue in your request. See the updated answer (Header  and  How to send request)

Comment: Added Headers and it still hit 404 (Not Found) error